How can I run a command after it has been opened with openwith?
(setq openwith-associations
      (list
       (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("flac" "mp3" "wav"))
             "cmus-remote -q" '(file) )

This works, but I have to issue the command cmus-remote -n to actually have it play the loaded song.
How can I run this command after?;)
